# Create php array based on specific rule

Tags: php

I need to create php array from the string, and then after parse the array.

So, the rules are like this:

```
{Test1|Test2} {Test3|Test4}
```

Parse this string and make it to be php array like this:

```
[
    'Test1' => Test2,
    'Test3' => Test4,
]
```

and this is something that I succeded with preg_match:

```
preg_match('/\{(.+)?\|(.+)}/', $attributeValue, $matches);
```

but there is another condition that I could not solve with preg_match and that is:

```
 {1|1 Test ({5622} text)}
```

where result would be

```
[
    '1' => 1 Test ({5622} text),
]
```

Basically , I cannot solve this when curly brackets are inside of the condition, I always get some unexpected result. Please, help me go in the right direction, I don't know if the preg_match is the best solution for my case.

Comment: Why not using json instead of a customized format (re-inventing the wheel)?

Comment: Because later I need to manipulate the data, and add different values into it. Test1 and Test2 are now hardcoded for showing the stackoverflow the problem, but that is not the actual value.

Comment: _later I need to manipulate the data..._ This should work with json perfectly

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand. Your help with this issue is to tell me to use json?

Comment: _“Your help with this issue is to tell me to use json?”_ - unless you have an actual reason to roll your own data format (and “I need to edit this later” isn’t one), that _is_ pretty solid advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string first.

**Steps:**

1) `explode()` string with `} {`.

2) Now, loop over resulting array.

3) In the loop, replace any `{` and `}`

4) Again, in the loop `explode()` by `|`.

5) You will get two string (array elements).

6) First element is your desired key and second is the desired value.

7) Append the key value pair to a new blank array.

8) Enjoy!!!

[Working Code:](https://3v4l.org/oK7uT)

```
<?php
$string = '{Test1|Test2} {Test3|Test4}';
$finalArray = array();
$asArr = explode( '} {', $string );
$find = ['{', '}'];
$replace = ['', ''];
foreach( $asArr as $val ){
 $val = str_replace($find, $replace, $val);
  $tmp = explode( '|', $val );
  $finalArray[ $tmp[0] ] = $tmp[1];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($finalArray);
echo '</pre>';
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Test1] => Test2
    [Test3] => Test4
)
```

Another version of the same code with less lines of code:

```
$string = "{Test1|Test2} {Test3|Test4}";
$string = str_replace('{', '', $string);
$arr = array_filter(explode('}', $string));
foreach($arr as $item){
 $item = explode('|', $item);
 $result[trim($item[0])] = trim($item[1]);
}
echo '<pre>';print_r($result);echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code get your desire output. There is no need to use preg_match.

`$string = "{Test1|Test2} {Test3|Test4}";`

```
$string_array = array_filter(explode('}', $string));
$result = [];
foreach($stringarray as $item){
  $item = str_replace('{', '', $item);
  $item_array = explode('|', $item);
  $result[$item_array[0]] = $item_array[1];
}
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
```

**Output:**

```
Array
(
    [Test1] => Test2
    [ Test3] => Test4
)
```